# How to integrate game logic in game engines

Tags: c#, .net, game-engine

Recently I'm working on a 2d game engine example in .Net with C#. My main problem is that I can't figure out how I should include the game logic within the game. Currently I have a base engine which is a set of classes that they are running sub-systems like `Render`, `Sound`, `Input` and `Core` functionality. There is an editor which helps the user to add resources, build levels, write scripts and other stuffs.

I came up with an idea to use `Reflection` and `CSharpCodeProvider` from my editor for compile the written codes, in this way I can get an executable of my product too. This way is quite well but I would like to know that, what's really the solution and architecture to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends way too much on the type of game - some of them can be included in the main loop, but RPGs may need full-on rules engines...

Comment: Assume it on 2d platform. BTW, I don't have any problem with events. The main loop could run the the `Step` event or each frame for example. No problem with it at all.

Comment: Do your user specify a game logic with `C#` ?

Comment: I'd try asking this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes the scripting language is with C# right now because I can't consist any other embeddable lang for now. The game needs compilation and `CSharpCodeProvider` is the only way for me to do it meantime.

Comment: @Beska, I didn't pay attention, sorry for that! I saw the `game-engine` tag here and I thought it might be a good place to ask.

Comment: @MahanGM, no apologies necessary.  I just thought you might just get better results over there, considering the focus.

Comment: 2D, 3D, text-based, doesn't matter.  It's the backend sim-side that matters, and it sounds like you may be heading towards a completely rule-based engine.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends how you designed your engine. It can't be just pieces of libraries that are responsible for different things like render, sound, input, etc. You have to have a piece that combines them together. The main two approaches are scene graph or component model. This is the module that will combine it all. Get input pass it to the entity or the component, execute some script, play some sfx, apply some transformation, send the transformed entity to the rendering pipeline. In this flow the **execute some script** is what you want to integrate. There are many ways to do it. Best way to do it is if these scripts come from your editor. They will be associated with entities templates, entity instances, triggers, UI elements, input devices. Engine should not know anything specific about the entities. Their templates should be defined in the editor and placed in the world again using the editor.

**Edit: Some more details.**

Assuming that you completely want to skip the application part and everything game specific is scripted in your editor. Then your Engine needs to have a main loop and update and draw your scene. A simple start is Update then Draw your scene as fast as you can without any wait in your loop.

Now assuming you have component model... Each component will have it's update and that update is the code you script. You have to create some interfaces that your components can access from the engine. For example your draw component template will have a property model and in it's update will call DrawModel on the engine and pass that model. Some other gamepad component will need from it's update to query what buttons were pressed or released. Will also need some to be able to find other components in the entity so that it can modify the position or the velocity of the physics component.

You have to start writing basic components of a basic entity and you will figure out what you don't have access to from your scripting. And then you have to expose it to your scripting layer. But think twice before exposing every single function. The simpler the API the better.

**Edit: How to compile script at runtime**

IronPython can evaluate code without compilation if you have .NET implementation of JavaScript I bet it can do it too. Here is a C# way to compile your script... If your editor is in C# I'll suggest you compile the separate assemblies in your editor.

```
    private Assembly Compile(string fileName)
    {
        CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, fileName);

        return cr.CompiledAssembly;
    }
```

Comment: You're right. Actually I know the engines flow but I don't know how I should implement this part of flow in my engine. Even with your speech I can't figure the way!

Comment: Thanks for details. I'm actually doing this right now in my engine. As I said before there is no problem with the time or place of performing scripts rather than I don't know how I should give the script to my engine and say: 'Hey, run it for me!'. I tried something like IronPython and JavaScript wrapper but they both need to compile the code each time that you want to run your script. This way it's like an application which it isn't compiled at first and it should compile its code at run-time.

Comment: Thanks @Aleks. I said it in my first post, I'm doing this right now `Reflection`. Compiling the exact C# code would be dangerous as other individuals have said.